# Why align-end does not work in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I use vuetify layout, and I wanna make button at right side, but I found `align-end` which is vuetify property does not work, I use `offset-xs9` to make button right side, but the button is being center in `v-flex`, how to make it on end ? help thanks

code like:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-layout row wrap  align-end>
      <v-flex xs3 offset-xs9 align-end>
        <div>
          <v-btn primary dark>Normal</v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

and [online codepen](https://codepen.io/dxcqcv/pen/RZOqWE)

Answer (score 30):

Vuetify's grid uses [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

- `align-*` operates on the vertical axis
- you want to use `justify-*` for the child to translate it horizontally
- `align-*` and `justify-*` only work on flex containers, so you can either use a `v-layout` instead of the `v-flex`, or just use both attributes on the same `v-layout`

Here is a [fixed pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbxWaR?editors=1000) for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, you save me a lot of time

Comment: This is a great answer. One comment though, the `justify` works on the main direction axis and the `align` works on the secondary axis. When using `row`, the main axis is horizontal and the secondary is vertical. When using `column`, it's the other way around (e.g: `<v-layout row> ... </v-layout>` vs `<v-layout column> ... </v-layout>`. Didn't understand "use a `v-layout` instead of the `v-flex` though. You need to use `v-flex` inside `v-layout`.

Answer (score 12):

Kael answer here is good, but I feel like there is more to be explained here.

First problem here is using `xs3 offset-xs9`:

```
<v-flex xs3 offset-xs9 align-end>
```

This will not allow us to use the `flexbox` grid system to place the content in a meaningful place (as you have described yourself).

The second problem was misusing Vuetify's flexbox grid properties correctly, for example, using the `align-end` on both `v-layout` and `v-flex`.

```
<v-layout row wrap  align-end>
      <v-flex xs3 offset-xs9 align-end>
```

Here's what we are after:

1. A layout that will place all content in the far right of itself
2. A container that will take up only the needed size of its content

Accomplishing these two objectives, will assure that your content will placed in the right end of the `v-layout` container, and you will avoid all kinds of weird spaces using `xs3` and `offset-xs-9` and so on.

So, for the `v-layout`, as Kael mentioned, we need to use `justtify-end`. Since your `v-layout`'s direction is `row`, we use `justify` for horizontal positioning.

And for the `v-flex` we need to make sure it only takes up the width of its content. We'll use `shrink` for that, so the final template should look like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-layout row wrap justify-end>
      <v-flex shrink>
        <v-btn primary dark>Normal</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `text-xs-right` in `<v-flex>` tag instead of `align-end` (see https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/layout/alignment).

Comment: `text-*-right` is for aligning text. Not flexbox containers. This is a very bad practice. See Kael Watts answer here for a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use v-spacer to push anything to right side.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <v-layout>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn primary dark>Normal</v-btn>
    </v-layout>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna align your element to the right-bottom corner, you can do it like this:

```
<v-img height="120px" class="white--text" :src="xxxx.img">
    <v-layout fill-height column ma-0 >
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-flex class="text-xs-right" shrink>
        <span class="grey darken-4">XXXXX</span>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</v-img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p class="text-xs-right">
      <v-btn class="d-inline-block">Normal</v-btn>
</p>
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56036881/edit) some explanation to your answer

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You're converting the container to a `inline-flex` and then treat the container as if it's an `inline` text holder with `text-*-right`. Look at Kael's answer here.