# Vuetify right align group of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I have a group of buttons that I'd like to be on the right side of the page, but `justify-end`/`justify='end'` is not working on `v-row`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-container>
        <v-form>
          <v-row justify='end'>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064376/why-align-end-does-not-work-in-vuetify) question, but using text align seems hacky, and I'm wondering if there is a better solution?

Comment: try putting the v-row with the justify='end' inside the v-col

Answer (score 40):

Add the `text-right` class to `<v-col>`:

```
<v-col class="text-right">
  <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
  <v-btn>Button 2</v-btn>
  <v-btn>Button 3</v-btn>
</v-col>
```

Comment: <v-btn :right="true" :absolute="true"></v-btn>

Comment: @BenSummerhayes Sadly, your tip does not work for me in Vuetify 3.1.3.

Answer (score 8):

Without changing the grid system try to add `<spacer/>` component in order to put `v-col` to the end of row like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-container tag="div">

        <v-form>
          <v-row justify="end">
            <spacer/>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
              <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>

      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use justify-end in a class on a v-row to get it to work. You can't use it on a v-col. DOCS: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/ You may need to play around with the spacing depending on where you put them but you can use the class to do that to avoid any styles.

```
    <v-form>
     <v-row class="justify-end">
       <v-btn class="mr-2">Button 1</v-btn>
       <v-btn class="mr-2">Button 1</v-btn>
       <v-btn class="mr-2">Button 1</v-btn>
     </v-row>
    </v-form>
```